# Image of a group equal to his kernel

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

If we have a function $f: G\rightarrow G$ , is there an example of a group $G$ that $imf=kerf$?
I try to think about the trivial group but there is another one?
Note: $f$ is Homomorphism.

Comment: Take $G=\mathbb Z^2$ and $f=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, namely $f(a,b)=(b,0)$, does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, there's many. Here's a family:

Take any group $H$, let $G=H\times H$ and consider
\begin{align}
H \times H &\longrightarrow H\times H, \\
(x, y) &\longmapsto (y, e_H).
\end{align}
Kernel and image are equal to $H\times\{e_H\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f\colon C_2\times C_2\rightarrow C_2\times C_2$, given by $(x,y)\mapsto (y,1)$.

Then $\ker(f)=C_2\times 1$ and $C_2\times 1=f(G)={\rm im}(G)$.

Answer (score 2):

All you are essentially asking for is a homomorphism $f: G\rightarrow H$ such that $\operatorname{im}(f)\cong\ker(f)$. To see this, alter the codomain of $f$ to make $f$ surjective, so $f: G\rightarrow\operatorname{im}(f)$, and then compose this with the isomorphism $\phi:\operatorname{im}(f)\rightarrow\ker(f)$ to get a map $\phi f$ which, after altering the codomain again, has the required properties.

Asking for homomorphisms with isomorphism $\operatorname{im}(f)\cong\ker(f)$ rather than equality $\operatorname{im}(f)=\ker(f)$ is easier but, as the above says, equivalent.

For example, we can see that any group of order $p^2$ gives us an example: such a group $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p$ (why?), and then the quotient group $G/N$ also has order $p$. If $f: G\rightarrow G/N$ is the associated homomorphism, we have $\operatorname{im}(f)\cong\ker(f)$ (equivalently, $N\cong G/N$), as up to isomorphism there is a single group of order $p$.

In particular, this means that cyclic groups of order $p^2$ give examples, which is a different class of examples from the other two answers.

Comment: Hello!  I couldn't ping you from Constructive Feedback.  It seems your work there was the most authentic, over time, wrt the room's purpose.  Ping me from the room, and I'll explain more the changes I've made.  But I would very much value you participation there, provided you have the time.